# Segmentation fault on second call when deleting first node

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I have this function for removing a certain node, then I loop it until all nodes with such value is removed from the list.

However, when I try to delete the first node it results to segmentation fault on the second call. It works fine for other parts of the list.

Here is the function I am calling to delete a node:

```
int delete(char* value, char* attribute, int attr_count){
    dataContainer = datadata; 
    dataList *temp, *prev;
    temp = dataContainer;
    prev = NULL;

    int g = 0;


    while(g < attr_count){
        if(strlen(dataContainer->attributes[g]) == 0){
            break;
        }
        if(!(strcmp(attribute, dataContainer->attributes[g]))){
            break;
        }
        g++;
    }

    while(temp){
        if(!(strcmp(temp->values[g], value))){
            if(prev == NULL) {
                dataContainer = temp->prev;
            }else{
                prev->prev = temp->prev;
            }
            free(temp);
            return 1;
        }
        temp = dataContainer;
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->prev;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: More information about the structure of `datacontainer` and `dataList` would help, as well as knowing where `datadata` comes from.

Comment: Have you *verified* that the data structure is valid before calling `delete`?

Comment: `dataList` is a struct with `char**` attributes and values. As well as, pointers prev and next. `dataContainer` and `datadata` are global variables of the type `dataList`.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes. I tried printing the whole list with no errors on its contents.

Comment: Is `attr_count` going to be valid for all the nodes? Is accesing `values[attr_count]` valid?

Comment: There are so many questions without knowing the context. Produce an MCVE.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Basically I have this linked list with 2 array of strings with the same number of elements. `attr_count` is the number of elements, so `values[attr_count]` may not be valid.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath The function checks which node in the list contains the `value` corresponding to the `attribute`, then deletes those nodes. It works  when the nodes found are not the first one, but if the first one matches, it produces segfault on the second call.

Comment: @StewieGuya: can you provide definition of `dataContainer`? it is more easier to help you when you show your structure.

Answer (score -1):

You can see my explanation in comments:

On second call datadata point on anything because tmp is freed on delete tmp you should update datadata like this datadata = tmp->next

```
    while(temp){
        if(!(strcmp(temp->values[g], value))){
            if(prev == NULL) {
                //when dataContainer->prev == NULL - you are in the head
                dataContainer = temp->prev;
                // if prev means previous in this case:
                // dataContainer = NULL, on the second call segmentation fault appears when calling starting from line dataContainer->attributes[g]
            }else{
                prev->prev = temp->prev;
            }
```